# Store old folder size in session php

Tags: php, session, state

I calculation a size of a folder using php and then store it in session, than i delete some files with other function and than calculate size of folder,

i want difference of both state old and new

But session stores every time new data and difference becomes 0

How do i maitain old size in session and prevent it from overwriting?

here is some part of code

```
 $this->size_session =  $currentsize;
  $_SESSION['oldsize']=$this->size_session;
```

i calculate new size after submit button

```
if($_REQUEST['file_delete']):

      $this->size_now = $currentsize;
     $_SESSION['oldsize']- $this->size_now;

   endif;
```

Comment: Is all your code in a single file ? Than you might require a condition to set session only if session is not set already.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the $_SESSION['oldsize'] to another variable BEFORE changing its value:

```
$old_size = $_SESSION['oldsize'];
if ($_REQUEST ... ):
   (...)
endif;
$difference = $old_size - $_SESSION['oldsize'];
```

Only that $_SESSION['oldsize'] is not a very good name, shouldn't it be 'actualsize', since you use it to store the actual size? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you typed this example manually or copy/paste, but:

```
$_SESSION['oldsize']- $this->size_now;
```

Should probably look like this:

```
$difference = $_SESSION['oldsize'] - $this->size_now;
```